# What's the purpose of an ice bath when preparing a nitration mix from KNO3?

Tags: synthesis, nitro-compounds

Most preparations for nitrocellulose from $\ce{(KNO3 + H2SO4)}$ mixture require the use of an ice bath during the process of dissolving $\ce{KNO3}$ into $\ce{H2SO4}$. Last time I did this I omitted this step and the nitrocellulose turned out to be of very low quality, but there's a number of other possible causes I can think of. Therefore, for the sake of troubleshooting I have this question: **What is the purpose of an ice bath during this step?** Is it to just limit the fuming, or does omitting it lead to decomposition of $\ce{HNO3}$ significant enough to impact the yield? I did not see any brown $\ce{NO2}$ fumes coming out, just the typical white mist of acid.

Comment: What generally can happen if you run an (exothermic) reaction at a higher starting temperature?

Comment: It is an exothermic reaction and generates a lot of heat.

Comment: It's not very exothermic, I imagine I'd have to dump all KNO3 at once to see it runaway. So it's just an additional safety measure?

Comment: Its certainly *also* a safety measure. You are aware that there are three different  basic types of nitrocellulose (mono, di, trinitrate) ?